# VS 2015 MVC OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Trying to debug an MVC5 web app - quite basic.  I've read articles and SO questions and answers and tried things until I'm blue in the face, and still can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Environment:
- VS 2015
- Windows 10 Professional N
- IISExpress
- MVC5 Web Application

I used VS 2013 up until about two weeks ago, switched to 2015 after an upgrade to Windows 10.  I've never seen this until switching to 2015.  The project(s) are hardly large and memory consuming, the database probably has a dozen tables with two dozen rows in it, and it's not even this single project (this just happens to be my most active one at the moment).

I've done the following:

- Verified no spikes in machine resources when this occurs (CPU < 10%, 14gb memory, pretty much flatlined at 6.7gb usage when trying start the debugging (same as normal when I'm not trying to start, no spikes at all))
- Played with debug settings sufficient to ensure that IISExpress doesn't stay running in the background after I close the session/stop debugging.
- Put IISExpress on the system try where I can manually stop application and close it
- Verified that there's no hanging processes of iisexpress continuing to run3
- Cleared out every temp folder and every other trick I've read about

Yet, every three or four times I hit F5 to start debugging, I get this error.  Sometimes I can see IISExpress running, kill it and retry and it works fine.  Sometimes the only thing that works is restarting Visual Studio.

I go through runs where I have to restart VS every other time I want to debug the application.  This is insane, and I can't find the slightest trace of a cause.

I'm at my wits end, enough to the point where I'm thinking this has to be a bug with VS2015, possibly when running on Windows 10 Professional (N)?

Anyone?  Please?!?!  (can provide full stack trace if someone thinks it helpful)

Comment: try these links https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3115, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764192/c-sharp-system-outofmemoryexception-in-visual-studio , http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/OutOfMemoryException

Comment: @Graham - I've done about 10 debugs without issue since setting IIS Express to use 64bit per the morteza blog suggestion - toss in an answer and I'll mark it accordingly.

Comment: Try to apply the methods mentioned in my answer on [Visual Studio 2015 extremely slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395686/visual-studio-2015-extremely-slow/34450140#comment57096450_34450140) and let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: @Graham you name appears in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317715/user-left-answer-in-comments-never-came-back?cb=1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/OutOfMemoryException

Specifically, setting the option to use 64 bit version of IIS:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects, top checkbox.  Make sure it's checked.

> [image]

and try these links also

- [C# - System.OutOfMemoryException in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764192/%E2%80%A6)
- http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3115

Comment: You should flesh out your answer here with summaries of the links, relevant quotes from the links, or both. Otherwise, if the links go down your answer will no longer be useful for future visitors.

Comment: I don't think he knew the details... I made an edit with the relevant info and screenshot I found so once approved we'll be in good shape.